# How to access the mobile device information using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For example,i need the results of Manufacuturer name, Model name, Android version. In xamarin forms they provided the device information and other hardware level stuffs achieved through xamarin essentials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/. Likewise i would like to get the details. please help me this. My current dart sdk version is 2.17.0-266.1.beta. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can get current device information from within the Flutter application by using the device_info_plus package.

This supports all kinds of platforms, including Android, iOS, macOS, web, Linux, and Windows.

Documentation:
https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Comment: I have included this package but it shows error on importing it in dart file. The error is as follows "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist."

Comment: Even i added the packages the problem exists. I don't know how to resolve this. Is there any way for accessing the hardware information via kotlin(Native) to flutter? Please help me on resolve this issue

Comment: have you tried to run - >  ‘flutter packages get’   from the root of your project?

Comment: post a screenshot of your error so I can understand clearly, I've had the same error before but different package, and I remember I forgot to run the 'flutter packages get', and it worked!.

Comment: kindly get the images from the drive link i shared below. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qzVTNsYMvW_Z-v3rtkWgdax_JefedAPg?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Go to your pubspec.yaml file, Check if this dependency it exists,

```
 dependencies:
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.3
```

then make sure to run this directly from the command line:

```
$ flutter packages get
```

now it should work!